# Embedding JApplet into a Google Chrome web page (HTML 5)

Tags: java, html, java-web-start, japplet

I have seen quite a few posts and tutorials on how to embed Java applets onto a web page, but most are either going with the obsolete `<applet>` tags or suggesting Java Web Start.

I have tried `<embed>` tag and `<object>` tag. None have worked. I would prefer not to go with Java Web Start, but is it the only option nowadays in order to view the applet on chrome? If I were to go with it, does the code have to be changed into a Java web application?

I admit that I am a beginner. Feel free to point out if I misunderstood the situation.

Helpful comments and tips are appreciated.

Code I tried.

```html
<embed archive="Redemption.jar" code="StartingPoint.class" width="200" height="200"type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6" pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ea.jsp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Java applet no longer works in any of the browsers.
Chrome was the first browser that stopped allowing Java applets. It used to work in Firefox but even Firefox stopped it a year ago.

Here Mozilla explains why it dropped support for Java applets:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/npapi-plugins

> Beginning in Firefox version 52 released March 7, 2017, installed
>   NPAPI plugins are no longer supported in Firefox, except for Adobe
>   Flash. Some of the plugins that will no longer load in Firefox, even
>   though they may be installed on your computer, include Java, Microsoft
>   Silverlight and Adobe Acrobat.

Why did browsers stopped supporting plugins such as Java Applet?

> Because they make your browsing slower, less secure and more likely
>   to crash.

Comment: So you can not even use java web start to deploy a applet?

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). (Yes, it includes JNLP / Java Web Start.)

Comment: That's right, even with java web start you cannot deploy an applet. Curious, why do you need to deploy applet anyways? why not make standalone Java application instead?